# scikit-learn transformer that bins data based on user supplied cut points

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to include a transformer in a scikit-learn pipeline that will bin a continuous data column into 4 values based on my own supplied cut points. The current arguments to [KBinsDiscretizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer) do not work mainly because the `strategy` argument only accepts `{‘uniform’, ‘quantile’, ‘kmeans’}`.

There is already the `cut()` function in **pandas** so I guess that I will need to create a custom transformer that wraps the `cut()` function behavior.

**Desired Behavior (not actual)**

```
X = [[-2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2]]
est = Discretizer(bins=[-float("inf"), -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, float("inf")], 
                  encode='ordinal')
est.fit(X)  
est.transform(X)
# >>> array([[0., 0., 1., 1., 2., 2., 3.]])
```

The result above assumes that the bins includes the rightmost edge and include the lowest. Like this `pd.cut()` command would provide:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.cut(np.array([-2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2]),
       [-float("inf"), -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, float("inf")], 
       labels=False, right=True, include_lowest=True)
# >>> array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what seems to work for me as a custom transformer. **scikit-learn** expects arrays of numerics so I'm not sure if you can implement the feature of `pd.cut()` that will return the labels. For this reason I've hard coded it to `False` in the implementation below.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class CutTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, bins, right=True, retbins=False,
                 precision=3, include_lowest=False,
                 duplicates='raise'):
        self.bins = bins
        self.right = right
        self.labels = False
        self.retbins = retbins
        self.precision = precision
        self.include_lowest = include_lowest
        self.duplicates = duplicates

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        assert isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame)
        for jj in range(X.shape[1]):
            X.iloc[:, jj] = pd.cut(x=X.iloc[:, jj].values, **self.__dict__)
        return X
```

**An Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'rand': np.random.rand(5)})
df
    rand
0   0.030653
1   0.542533
2   0.159646
3   0.963112
4   0.539530

ct = CutTransformer(bins=np.linspace(0, 1, 5))
ct.transform(df)
    rand
0   0
1   2
2   0
3   3
4   2
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to a custom transformer, which has more overhead, would be to use the `FunctionTransformer()` method which is good for stateless operations like this case where the bins are predefined.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

def ftransformer_cut(X, **kwargs):
    if 'labels' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['labels'] = False

    assert isinstance(X, np.ndarray)
    assert kwargs['labels'] == False

    for jj in range(X.shape[1]):
        X[:, jj] = pd.cut(x=X[:, jj], **kwargs)

    return X

pipeline = make_pipeline(
    FunctionTransformer(ftransformer_cut,
                        kw_args={'bins': np.linspace(0, 1, 5)})
)

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'rand': np.random.rand(5)})
    rand
0   0.823234
1   0.336883
2   0.713595
3   0.408184
4   0.038

pipeline.transform(df)
array([[3.],
       [1.],
       [2.],
       [1.],
       [0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue there is that you are only transforming the incoming data, not learning the bins from the training during fit stage and using that information during transform stage. Ideally you should be learning the bin edges during fit and assigning the bins during transform.